# How to resolve interactive session error in tensorflow (version 2.0.0a), python version 3.6.8, anaconda version 5.3.1?

Tags: tensorflow, interactive-session

I run the following code snippet

`from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np`

which returns the following error

`` AttributeError Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'InteractiveSession'  ``

I am using tensorflow version ('2.0.0-alpha0'), python 3.6.8 and anaconda 5.3.1. I tried running the codes in Jupyter notebook. I have mac OS Mojave 10.14.4

Many links in the Internet have asked us to install tensorflow-GPU but this is no longer supported in mac.

I also tried reinstalling tensorflow but its not working!

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently on windows 10 but I think it's the same for mac. The only solution I found was this:

uninstalling tensorflow version 2.0.0

```
pip uninstall tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0
```

and install version 1.13.1

```
pip install tensorflow
```